# Redirection using tee and sed

Tags: linux, sed, csh, tee

What am I doing wrong here? I don't get any `STDOUT` from `tee` but `test.log` is populated correctly.

```
perl test.pl | tee -i | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' > test.log
```

My goal is to sent everything printed by `test.pl` to `STDOUT` and dump a filtered version(using `sed`) of same to `test.log`

Comment: You're not giving a file name to `tee`

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 3):

After clarification:

The solution by Daniel Schelper is the correct one on normal human usable shells (google Why never to use csh). Unfortunately sometimes we do not have a choice, so one solution:

```
perl test.pl | tee /dev/stderr | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' > test.log
```

What this does is duplicate `stdout` to `stderr`, and pipes only `stdout` forward. The output from `perl` will be displayed on screen (through `stderr`). This has the obvious caveat that any real errors may be hidden. A safer solution may be:

```
perl test.pl > /tmp/temp.log; cat /tmp/tmp.log & sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' /tmp/tmp.log
```

which of course makes an extra file. The good options on csh usually involve more intermediate files compared to Bourne shells.

---

**Old answer**

`tee` should always be the last piped program (unless you want to log something midway I guess), and have a filename as an argument. The former is because the whole point is to see the output in the screen (not pass it on) and the second is because tee is usually not useful when it doesn't send output to a file as well.

As it currently stands, you are passing `stdout` through `tee` to the next pipe, `sed`, and that is dumping everything into `test.log` with the `>` operator. In fact, you should not have both `>` and `tee`:

```
perl test.pl | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' | tee test.log
```

to get results of `sed` both on screen and in your log. If I misunderstand and you in fact do want to log the results midway using tee

```
perl test.pl | tee mid.log | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' > test.log
```

Comment: My goal is to send everything printed by `test.pl` to `STDOUT` and dump a filtered version of same to `test.log`. How do I do it then?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Just got back - do you want to write that as your own answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bash, i.e. Posix compliance of the script is not important, then you can use a [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
perl test.pl | tee >(sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' > test.log)
```

Comment: I use `tcsh` and it says `Missing name for redirect.` when I execute the command

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
perl test.pl | tee -i /dev/stderr | sed -f sed.sed > test.log
```

The perl program will pump its output to stdout. The tee will take the stdout and accept it as stdin and pump it out to stderr and stdout. The sed program will take the stdout and accept it as stdin and pump it out stdout which redirects it to `test.log`. The stderr will be directed to the terminal.

N.B. This may incur unwanted side-effects.

Comment: I come 13 hours later and post at the same time as you, that's crazy.